# My discord bot command only works when i turn it off

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot and my ping command only works when I turn it off.

```py
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
TOKEN = 'lol this is the token but i dont want anyone getting in my bot'
```

This right here isn't working

```py
@client.command(name='ping')
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Pong!')
```

This is a booting script.

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Online')
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = 'Bot status',
        description = 'The discord bot is online and it works like a charm',
        colour = discord.Colour.blue()

    )
    embed.set_footer(text='Bot online')
    channel = client.get_channel(channel)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
    breaks = input('type stop to stop the bot.\n')
    if breaks == 'stop':
        embeder = discord.Embed(
            title = 'Bot status',
            description = 'The discord bot is offline.',
            colour = discord.Colour.blue()
        )
    embed.set_footer(text='Bot offline')
    await channel.send(embed=embeder)
    await client.close()


client.run(TOKEN)
```

There is an error code on the terminal and I don't know what it means,
I've tried everything to try to make it work, and it doesn't work.
[error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4k0jh.png)

Comment: can you add the error to your question, please?

Comment: If you're getting an error a really good idea would be to include it in the question...

Comment: finished with the error

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but there's an issue with your booting script right...

```
    if breaks == 'stop':
        embeder = discord.Embed(
            title = 'Bot status',
            description = 'The discord bot is offline.',
            colour = discord.Colour.blue()
        )
    embed.set_footer(text='Bot offline')
    await channel.send(embed=embeder)
    await client.close() # Right here
```

Your code is improperly indented there, so the run script automatically shuts the client down as soon as it hits this block of code.

Here's the fixed code:

```
    if breaks == 'stop':
        embeder = discord.Embed(
            title = 'Bot status',
            description = 'The discord bot is offline.',
            colour = discord.Colour.blue()
        )
        embed.set_footer(text='Bot offline')
        await channel.send(embed=embeder)
        await client.close()
```

I haven't tried this code on my IDE yet, so please do let me know if it works.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Using inputs in discord.py which is a complete async/await lib is a really bad idea, `input` is a blocking function and don't let code execute until you pass break in input command.

You should move that block code to another function and decorate the function as a command

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Online')
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = 'Bot status',
        description = 'The discord bot is online and it works like a charm',
        colour = discord.Colour.blue()

    )
    embed.set_footer(text='Bot online')
    channel = await client.fetch_channel(channel)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
    

@client.command(name='close')
async def close(ctx):
    embeder = discord.Embed(
            title = 'Bot status',
            description = 'The discord bot is offline.',
            colour = discord.Colour.blue()
        )
    embed.set_footer(text='Bot offline')
    await ctx.send(embed=embeder)
    await client.close()
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a problem with this a while ago, try closing all terminals (if you use visual studio code) or try to restart your computer.